# I installed the OpenJDK-7 but my runtime environment wasn't upgraded to 7?

Tags: java, openjdk

I installed openjdk-7-jdk, "javac" was version 7 but "java" was still version 1.6, any way around this? No updates are available.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the javac file in /usr/bin is still linking to your previous jdk. So you have to using `update-alternative` to configure it.

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

to get the list of JVMs and then use

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s NAME
```

to set the one you want.  It may warn about some missing links, in which case you'll need to install the missing package and run `update-java-alternatives` again.

Comment: When I run sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle, it gives me : "

    update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
    update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/jexec for jexec not registered, not setting.
    update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so for mozilla-javaplugin.so not registered, not setting.
    update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so. "

What is the matter? I use ubuntu12.04 amd64.